# TLS - Node.js server to Android app

Tags: android, security, node.js, network-programming, ssl

I'm starting a new project in the coming weeks but I have some questions related to the "design" of the app.

The app will be a server + database that talks to an Android app that also has it's own database (for offline use).

The connection will be used to exchange strings that are encrypted with a custom "protocol" (game network protocol encapsulated in TLS). This means that the app would have two layers of security :

1. TLS -> against MitM attacks
2. Custom protocol -> against "in-game hacks", like game packet tampering

My questions are the following :

- Is it possible to use TLS between node.js and Android ? Are there any good links on that subject ?

(I read there were some issues with the format of the certs that was different in java and node.js. It was related to OpenSSL and the `EVP_BytesToKey` function)

-- > [Encrypt with Node.js Crypto module and decrypt with Java (in Android app)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7787773/encrypt-with-node-js-crypto-module-and-decrypt-with-java-in-android-app)

--> http://olabini.com/blog/tag/evp_bytestokey/

- Is there a way of obfuscating the source code of the Android app so that the custom "protocol" can be decrypted client-side safely? Or should all the magic take place server side ?

(I don't want the decryption source-code to be visible for users to dissect the custom protocol and start developing hacks.)

- Any tips or links on increasing the security of my node.js server in general ?

(I heard some people talking about Nginx proxies, but since I'm not serving webpages does it still make sense ? Wouldn't it overload the server ?)

Thank you alot in advance !

Answer (score 1):

(In)[Security though obscurity](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Security_through_obscurity) does not solve the real security problems you face.  What you are describing is **not** how games protect themselves from attack.  SSL/TLS does prevent against MITM attacks,  however your attacker isn't just a MITM,  he is a user of your software.   If the app can make the SSL/TLS connection, then the attacker can also make this connection and should assume that the attacker **will always** full access to the API you provide.

Cryptography cannot solve [CWE-602: client side enforcement of server side security](http://cwe.mitre.org/data/definitions/602.html).  A database merge between the client's offline database and the server is trusting the client's data,  and there for a violation of CWE-602.  In this attack the attacker doesn't need access to the API, he could just modify the sqlite database locally.