# encrypt the audio file by android and decrypt it by backend sails js

Tags: audio, encryption, sails.js, node-crypto

I want to encrypt the audio file  by android and decrypt it by backend sails js. I developed the program for that but I got error in `sails js`  like

```
error:06065064:digital envelope routines:EVP_DecryptFinal_ex:bad decrypt
```

[image]

This is my source code for encrypt the audio file in android

```
     final String ALGORITHM = "blowfish";
     String keyString = "DesireSecretKey";

    private void encrypt(String file) throws Exception {

        File extStore = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory();
        File inputFile = new File(file);
        File encryptedFile = new 
        File(extStore+"/Movies/encryptAudio.amr");
        doCrypto(Cipher.ENCRYPT_MODE, inputFile, encryptedFile);
     }



     private  void doCrypto(int cipherMode, File inputFile,
                                 File outputFile) throws Exception {

        Key secretKey = new 
        SecretKeySpec(keyString.getBytes(),ALGORITHM);
        Cipher cipher = Cipher.getInstance(ALGORITHM);
        cipher.init(cipherMode, secretKey);

        FileInputStream inputStream = new FileInputStream(inputFile);
        byte[] inputBytes = new byte[(int) inputFile.length()];
        inputStream.read(inputBytes);

        byte[] outputBytes = cipher.doFinal(inputBytes);

        FileOutputStream outputStream = new 
        FileOutputStream(outputFile);
        outputStream.write(outputBytes);

        inputStream.close();
        outputStream.close();

    }
```

I installed the crypto , fs libraries in sails js backend by following command
        npm install crypto 
        npm install fs

This is my source code for decrypt the audio file in sails js

```
   function decrypt() {
        var crypto = require('crypto'),
        algorithm = 'blowfish',
        password = 'DesireSecretKey';

        var fs = require('fs');

      // input file
        var r = fs.createReadStream(config.UPLOAD_FILES_PATH 
        +'/encryptAudio.amr');

     var decrypt = crypto.createDecipher(algorithm, password,"");

   // write file
    var w = fs.createWriteStream(config.AUDIO_PATH+'decryptAudio.amr');

   // start pipe
      r.pipe(decrypt).pipe(w);
  }
```

Encryption is working properly & i can get the encrypted audio file.But the issue is i couldn't get the decrypted audio file by sails js. Can you identify the issue?

Answer (score 0):

maybe the answer to this question might help as you are using Java's library for cryptography this should pretty much guide you in right direction.
[Encrypt with Node.js Crypto module and decrypt with Java (in Android app)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7787773/encrypt-with-node-js-crypto-module-and-decrypt-with-java-in-android-app)
I would have mentioned this in comments section but I do not have enough reputation points to comment.
This is opposite of what you are trying to achieve but still it could help you to analyze your issue.